# Watir - Finding parent div of specific child with attribute value

Tags: ruby, watir

I'm a total newbie with Ruby and Watir.  I have the following example html structure:

```
<div class="class1">
    <a class="class2" title="theTestTitle" href="#">
    <ul class="the-summary">
        <li class="class3">
        <li class="class4">
        <li class="class5">
        <li class="class6">
    </ul>
</div>
```

My goal is to test what is in the following div but first I need to get that div to test with.  Is there a way of using the link attribute title to find the div I need.  So in example above find div where child link has title="theTestTitle"?

Also after I have this div in a variable can I use xpath to search just in that div or?

Answer (score 3):

You can get the link and then get its parent using the `parent` method:

```
browser.link(:title, 'theTestTitle').parent
```

Or you can get the div directly by using xpath:

```
#In Watir-classic:
browser.div(:xpath, '//div[./a[@title="theTestTitle"]]')

#In Watir-webdriver:
browser.element(:xpath, '//div[./a[@title="theTestTitle"]]').to_subtype
```